# I opened an Existing flutter app in android studio but it shows error

Tags: flutter, dart

I opened an existing flutter app in android studio but 2 errors appearing in the AS

1st error is **DART SDK IS NOT CONFIGURED**

2nd error is **NO DEVICE**

[image]

Comment: You can open dart setting then select flutter sdk path and click on package get.

Comment: From where I can get dart setting???

Comment: Check your screenshot right side of "Download Dart SDK"

Comment: it takes me to browser to download chcolate dart sdk